# Find cache by part of key name in RedisInsight

Tags: redis, redisinsights

I'm using RedisInsight to connect to my Redis database.

There are several keys, like

```
gateway:CNE:historical
time_series:45:day=None
gateway:45:historical
...
```

Now I want to filter only those, which have `gateway` in name. How to do that? I've tried `KEYS gateway*` and `KEYS *gateway*` , but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RedisInsight there is a dedicated UI control on the Browser page to filter by key name, and the `gateway*` should perfectly work.
However one notice: RedisInsight scans per 10,000 keys, so if your database has more, click the "Scan more" button to scan an additional 10,000 keys (the screen is attached).

`KEYS gateway*` CLI command should also work, though this command scans the entire keyspace so it is recommended to not run it in production.

If it didn't work - check:

1. the lower and upper cases.
2. if you use database indexes (`SELECT` command)

[image]